# Unable to connect to mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to coding and am unable to connect to the database i have created and i really cannot move further because i need to access that in order to add , display and manipulate data . could someone please help me understand what it is i am doing wrong ? ????? my php and html form are given below . i have created a database with a table but information doesnt get added to it .

```js
<form id="details" action="Seller.php" method="post">
<div class="textdiv">

Enter the title for the advertisemennt 
<input type="text" id="adtitle"></input><br/>
Sellers name
<input type="text" id="sellersname"> </input><br/>
Email id
<input type="text" id="email"></input><br/>
Enter A brief description of the necessary details for the product
<textarea  rows="10" cols="30" id="description"></textarea><br/>
<br/>
Choose a category
<select name="product">
<option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
<option value="Cars">Cars</option>
<option value="pets">pets</option>
<option value="furniture">furniture</option>
<option value="appliances">appliances</option>
<option value="books">books</option>
<option value="other">other</option>
</select>
<br/>
<br/>
Enter your mobile number 

<input type="text" id="phone number"> </input> <br/> <br/>

your phone number will be kept private .<br/> <br/>
Selling price 
<input type="text" id="base"></input><br>
Cutoff price ( the price below which you will not sell )
<input type="text" id="cutoff"></input><br>
</form></div>
```

```html
<?php
define (DB_NAME,'seller');
define (DB_USER,'root');
define (DB_PASSWORD,'');
define (DB_HOST,'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link)
{die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$link);

if(!$db_selected){die('Cant use '.DB_NAME.':'.mysql_error();}

echo'SUCESS';
$value = $_POST['adtitle'];
$value2 = $_POST['sellersname'];
$value3 = $_POST['email'];
$value4 = $_POST['description'];
$value5 = $_POST['category'];
$value6 = $_POST['phone number'];
$value7 = $_POST['base'];
$value8 = $_POST['cutoff'];

$sql ="INSERT INTO seller (adtitle,sellersname,email,description,category,phone number,base,cutoff) VALUES('$value',$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5,$value6,$value7,$value8)";


mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: You have set up the sql query but you are not executing it. Use `mysql_query` to execute the query

Comment: Better yet, don't use the `mysql` functions at all, use `mysqli` and or prepared statments

Comment: @Hosseini yes you are right PDO is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for connecting to mysql database.

```
$serverName = "localhost";
$userName = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "seller";

$db = new mysqli( $serverName, $userName, $password, $database );

if ( $db -> connect_errno ) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db -> connect_errno . ") " . $db -> connect_error;
} else {
    echo "You are connected to your database. <br><br>";
}
```